# How can I separate part of an UV island without distorting anything else?

Tags: uv

I made a model, unwraped it and textured it, but then I noticed, that small part of which I thought it wouldn't be too exposed and therefore I didn't texture it too well (it was a nostril and I made it together with the inside of the beak, which I left just some darker red) and then I noticed, that it's clearly visible. I don't want to make it a second material or to make the whole texture again. It's just four quads, could I somehow separate them from the rest of the island and make it one small island of it's own?

Comment: Mark seams around those 4 quads ?

Comment: you don't even need to mark the seems, if you select only those faces and unwrap, they will appear as an island of their own.

Comment: Do as Yvain explains. Very simple.

Comment: thanks, that works fine, but I realized, that I completly forgot about pins...